# IBM Bluemix deployment fails for node.js app

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, buildpack

Error when deploying a simple node.js app (which works locally):

```
ERR     mv: cannot move ‘/tmp/node-v0.10.40-linux-x64/bin’ to ‘/tmp/staged/app/vendor/node/bin’: Directory not empty
ERR mv: cannot move ‘/tmp/node-v0.10.40-linux-x64/include’ to ‘/tmp/staged/app/vendor/node/include’: Directory not empty
ERR mv: cannot move ‘/tmp/node-v0.10.40-linux-x64/licenses’ to ‘/tmp/staged/app/vendor/node/licenses’: Directory not empty
ERR mv: cannot move ‘/tmp/node-v0.10.40-linux-x64/share’ to ‘/tmp/staged/app/vendor/node/share’: Directory not empty
OUT -----> Build failed
OUT        Your build failed!
OUT        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
OUT        http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport
OUT Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
ERR encountered error: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
```

This fails with both the default node buildpack and the node sdk `>cf push -b sdk-for-nodejs_v2_5-20150902-1526`. 
The `cf` tail logs contain only the same mv errors.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you please add to the question your package.json and manifest.ylm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked was to use the latest node.js buildpack:

`cf push -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/buildpack-nodejs.git`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cf logs appname --recent` as mentioned in the debugging staging errors for Node.js article in the link below:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/debugging.html#debug_stgerr

Comment: The logs did not show anything except the `mv` errors, unfortunately. The answer was to use the latest node buildpack: